# Airflow worker is not listening to default rabbitmq queue

Tags: rabbitmq, airflow

I have configured Airflow with rabbitmq broker, the services:

```
airflow worker
airflow scheduler
airflow webserver
```

are running without any errors. The scheduler is pushing the tasks to execute on `default` rabbitmq queue:

[image]
[image]

Even I tried `airflow worker -q=default` - worker still not receiving tasks to run. My airflow.cfg settings file:

```
[core]
# The home folder for airflow, default is ~/airflow
airflow_home = /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow

# The folder where your airflow pipelines live, most likely a
# subfolder in a code repository
# This path must be absolute
dags_folder = /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/dags

# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/logs

remote_base_log_folder = 
remote_log_conn_id =
# Use server-side encryption for logs stored in S3
encrypt_s3_logs = False
# DEPRECATED option for remote log storage, use remote_base_log_folder instead!
s3_log_folder =

executor = CeleryExecutor

# The SqlAlchemy connection string to the metadata database.
# SqlAlchemy supports many different database engine, more information
# their website
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://name:password@ksaprice_postgres:5432/airflow

sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5

# The SqlAlchemy pool recycle is the number of seconds a connection
# can be idle in the pool before it is invalidated. This config does
# not apply to sqlite.
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600

# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# When not using pools, tasks are run in the "default pool",
# whose size is guided by this config element
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16

# Whether to load the examples that ship with Airflow. It's good to
# get started, but you probably want to set this to False in a production
# environment
load_examples = True

# Where your Airflow plugins are stored
plugins_folder = /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/plugins

# Secret key to save connection passwords in the db
fernet_key = SomeKey

# Whether to disable pickling dags
donot_pickle = False

# How long before timing out a python file import while filling the DagBag
dagbag_import_timeout = 30

# The class to use for running task instances in a subprocess
task_runner = BashTaskRunner

# If set, tasks without a `run_as_user` argument will be run with this user
# Can be used to de-elevate a sudo user running Airflow when executing tasks
default_impersonation =

# What security module to use (for example kerberos):
security =

# Turn unit test mode on (overwrites many configuration options with test
# values at runtime)
unit_test_mode = False

[cli]
# In what way should the cli access the API. The LocalClient will use the
# database directly, while the json_client will use the api running on the
# webserver
api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
endpoint_url = http://localhost:8080

[api]
# How to authenticate users of the API
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default

[operators]
# The default owner assigned to each new operator, unless
# provided explicitly or passed via `default_args`
default_owner = Airflow
default_cpus = 1
default_ram = 512
default_disk = 512
default_gpus = 0


[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
base_url = http://localhost:8080

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 8080

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120

# Number of workers to refresh at a time. When set to 0, worker refresh is
# disabled. When nonzero, airflow periodically refreshes webserver workers by
# bringing up new ones and killing old ones.
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1

# Number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.
worker_refresh_interval = 30

# Secret key used to run your flask app
secret_key = temporary_key

# Number of workers to run the Gunicorn web server
workers = 4

# The worker class gunicorn should use. Choices include
# sync (default), eventlet, gevent
worker_class = sync

# Log files for the gunicorn webserver. '-' means log to stderr.
access_logfile = -
error_logfile = -

# Expose the configuration file in the web server
expose_config = False

# Set to true to turn on authentication:
# http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/security.html#web-authentication
authenticate = False

# Filter the list of dags by owner name (requires authentication to be enabled)
filter_by_owner = False

# Filtering mode. Choices include user (default) and ldapgroup.
# Ldap group filtering requires using the ldap backend
#
# Note that the ldap server needs the "memberOf" overlay to be set up
# in order to user the ldapgroup mode.
owner_mode = user

# Default DAG orientation. Valid values are:
# LR (Left->Right), TB (Top->Bottom), RL (Right->Left), BT (Bottom->Top)
dag_orientation = LR

# Puts the webserver in demonstration mode; blurs the names of Operators for
# privacy.
demo_mode = False

# The amount of time (in secs) webserver will wait for initial handshake
# while fetching logs from other worker machine
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5

# By default, the webserver shows paused DAGs. Flip this to hide paused
# DAGs by default
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False    

[celery]
# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
celeryd_concurrency = 16

# When you start an airflow worker, airflow starts a tiny web server
# subprocess to serve the workers local log files to the airflow main
# web server, who then builds pages and sends them to users. This defines
# the port on which the logs are served. It needs to be unused, and open
# visible from the main web server to connect into the workers.
worker_log_server_port = 8793    
# The Celery broker URL. Celery supports RabbitMQ, Redis and experimentally
# a sqlalchemy database. Refer to the Celery documentation for more
# information.

#broker_url = pyamqp://user:pw@ksaprice_rabbitmq/ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh
broker_url = amqp://user:pw@ksaprice_rabbitmq/ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh
    # Another key Celery setting
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://name:pw@ksaprice_postgres:5432/airflow

# Celery Flower is a sweet UI for Celery. Airflow has a shortcut to start
# it `airflow flower`. This defines the IP that Celery Flower runs on
flower_host = 0.0.0.0

# This defines the port that Celery Flower runs on
flower_port = 5555

# Default queue that tasks get assigned to and that worker listen on.
default_queue = default


[scheduler]
# Task instances listen for external kill signal (when you clear tasks
# from the CLI or the UI), this defines the frequency at which they should
# listen (in seconds).
job_heartbeat_sec = 5

# The scheduler constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the
# scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines
# how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5

# after how much time should the scheduler terminate in seconds
# -1 indicates to run continuously (see also num_runs)
run_duration = -1

# after how much time a new DAGs should be picked up from the filesystem
min_file_process_interval = 0

dag_dir_list_interval = 300

# How often should stats be printed to the logs
print_stats_interval = 30

child_process_log_directory = /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/logs/scheduler

# Local task jobs periodically heartbeat to the DB. If the job has
# not heartbeat in this many seconds, the scheduler will mark the
# associated task instance as failed and will re-schedule the task.
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300

# Turn off scheduler catchup by setting this to False.
# Default behavior is unchanged and
# Command Line Backfills still work, but the scheduler
# will not do scheduler catchup if this is False,
# however it can be set on a per DAG basis in the
# DAG definition (catchup)
catchup_by_default = True

# Statsd (https://github.com/etsy/statsd) integration settings
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow

# The scheduler can run multiple threads in parallel to schedule dags.
# This defines how many threads will run. However airflow will never
# use more threads than the amount of cpu cores available.
max_threads = 2

authenticate = False
```

`rabbitmqctl report`:

```
Reporting server status on {{2017,8,3},{13,15,38}}


Status of node ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0
[{pid,115},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.10"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.10"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.10"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.10"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.14.2"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.10"},
      {rabbit_common,
          "Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client",
          "3.6.10"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.3.4"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.1"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.1"},
      {cowboy,"Small, fast, modular HTTP server.","1.0.4"},
      {cowlib,"Support library for manipulating Web protocols.","1.0.2"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.3.0"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.1"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.3"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.7.2"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.0.3"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.12"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.4","4.0.4"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.0.2"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.2"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.1.1"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,70578840},
      {connection_readers,0},
      {connection_writers,0},
      {connection_channels,0},
      {connection_other,2832},
      {queue_procs,192136},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,2117704},
      {other_proc,17561640},
      {mnesia,88872},
      {metrics,207264},
      {mgmt_db,771920},
      {msg_index,48056},
      {other_ets,2535184},
      {binary,910704},
      {code,24680786},
      {atom,1033401},
      {other_system,20632773}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"},{http,15672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,830581964},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,55911219200},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,1048476},
      {total_used,8},
      {sockets_limit,943626},
      {sockets_used,0}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,338}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,3204},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]

Cluster status of node ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0
[{nodes,[{disc,[ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0]}]},
 {running_nodes,[ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0]},
 {cluster_name,<<"ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0,[]}]}]

Application environment of node ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0
[{amqp_client,[{prefer_ipv6,false},{ssl_options,[]}]},
 {asn1,[]},
 {compiler,[]},
 {cowboy,[]},
 {cowlib,[]},
 {crypto,[]},
 {inets,[]},
 {kernel,
     [{error_logger,tty},
      {inet_default_connect_options,[{nodelay,true}]},
      {inet_dist_listen_max,25672},
      {inet_dist_listen_min,25672}]},
 {mnesia,[{dir,"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/ksaprice_rabbitmq"}]},
 {os_mon,
     [{start_cpu_sup,false},
      {start_disksup,false},
      {start_memsup,false},
      {start_os_sup,false}]},
 {public_key,[]},
 {rabbit,
     [{auth_backends,[rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
      {auth_mechanisms,['PLAIN','AMQPLAIN']},
      {background_gc_enabled,false},
      {background_gc_target_interval,60000},
      {backing_queue_module,rabbit_priority_queue},
      {channel_max,0},
      {channel_operation_timeout,15000},
      {cluster_keepalive_interval,10000},
      {cluster_nodes,{[],disc}},
      {cluster_partition_handling,ignore},
      {collect_statistics,fine},
      {collect_statistics_interval,5000},
      {config_entry_decoder,
          [{cipher,aes_cbc256},
           {hash,sha512},
           {iterations,1000},
           {passphrase,undefined}]},
      {credit_flow_default_credit,{400,200}},
      {default_permissions,[<<".*">>,<<".*">>,<<".*">>]},
      {default_user,<<"guest">>},
      {default_user_tags,[administrator]},
      {default_vhost,<<"/">>},
      {delegate_count,16},
      {disk_free_limit,50000000},
      {disk_monitor_failure_retries,10},
      {disk_monitor_failure_retry_interval,120000},
      {enabled_plugins_file,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"},
      {error_logger,tty},
      {fhc_read_buffering,false},
      {fhc_write_buffering,true},
      {frame_max,131072},
      {halt_on_upgrade_failure,true},
      {handshake_timeout,10000},
      {heartbeat,60},
      {hipe_compile,false},
      {hipe_modules,
          [rabbit_reader,rabbit_channel,gen_server2,rabbit_exchange,
           rabbit_command_assembler,rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,rabbit_basic,
           rabbit_event,lists,queue,priority_queue,rabbit_router,rabbit_trace,
           rabbit_misc,rabbit_binary_parser,rabbit_exchange_type_direct,
           rabbit_guid,rabbit_net,rabbit_amqqueue_process,
           rabbit_variable_queue,rabbit_binary_generator,rabbit_writer,
           delegate,gb_sets,lqueue,sets,orddict,rabbit_amqqueue,
           rabbit_limiter,gb_trees,rabbit_queue_index,
           rabbit_exchange_decorator,gen,dict,ordsets,file_handle_cache,
           rabbit_msg_store,array,rabbit_msg_store_ets_index,rabbit_msg_file,
           rabbit_exchange_type_fanout,rabbit_exchange_type_topic,mnesia,
           mnesia_lib,rpc,mnesia_tm,qlc,sofs,proplists,credit_flow,pmon,
           ssl_connection,tls_connection,ssl_record,tls_record,gen_fsm,ssl]},
      {lazy_queue_explicit_gc_run_operation_threshold,1000},
      {log_levels,[{connection,info}]},
      {loopback_users,[]},
      {memory_monitor_interval,2500},
      {mirroring_flow_control,true},
      {mirroring_sync_batch_size,4096},
      {mnesia_table_loading_retry_limit,10},
      {mnesia_table_loading_retry_timeout,30000},
      {msg_store_credit_disc_bound,{4000,800}},
      {msg_store_file_size_limit,16777216},
      {msg_store_index_module,rabbit_msg_store_ets_index},
      {msg_store_io_batch_size,4096},
      {num_ssl_acceptors,1},
      {num_tcp_acceptors,10},
      {password_hashing_module,rabbit_password_hashing_sha256},
      {plugins_dir,
          "/usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.10/plugins"},
      {plugins_expand_dir,
          "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/ksaprice_rabbitmq-plugins-expand"},
      {queue_explicit_gc_run_operation_threshold,1000},
      {queue_index_embed_msgs_below,4096},
      {queue_index_max_journal_entries,32768},
      {reverse_dns_lookups,false},
      {sasl_error_logger,tty},
      {server_properties,[]},
      {ssl_allow_poodle_attack,false},
      {ssl_apps,[asn1,crypto,public_key,ssl]},
      {ssl_cert_login_from,distinguished_name},
      {ssl_handshake_timeout,5000},
      {ssl_listeners,[]},
      {ssl_options,[]},
      {tcp_listen_options,
          [{backlog,128},
           {nodelay,true},
           {linger,{true,0}},
           {exit_on_close,false}]},
      {tcp_listeners,[5672]},
      {trace_vhosts,[]},
      {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
      {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio,0.5}]},
 {rabbit_common,[]},
 {rabbitmq_management,
     [{cors_allow_origins,[]},
      {cors_max_age,1800},
      {http_log_dir,none},
      {listener,[{port,15672}]},
      {load_definitions,none},
      {management_db_cache_multiplier,5},
      {process_stats_gc_timeout,300000},
      {stats_event_max_backlog,250}]},
 {rabbitmq_management_agent,
     [{rates_mode,basic},
      {sample_retention_policies,
          [{global,[{605,5},{3660,60},{29400,600},{86400,1800}]},
           {basic,[{605,5},{3600,60}]},
           {detailed,[{605,5}]}]}]},
 {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,[]},
 {ranch,[]},
 {sasl,[{errlog_type,error},{sasl_error_logger,tty}]},
 {ssl,[]},
 {stdlib,[]},
 {syntax_tools,[]},
 {xmerl,[]}]

Connections:

Channels:

Queues on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:
pid     name    durable auto_delete     arguments       owner_pid       exclusive       messages_ready  messages_unacknowledged messages        reductions      policy  exclusive_consumer_pid  exclusive_consumer_tag  consumers       consumer_utilisation    memory  slave_pids      synchronised_slave_pids recoverable_slaves      state   garbage_collection      messages_ram    messages_ready_ram      messages_unacknowledged_ram     messages_persistent     message_bytes   message_bytes_ready     message_bytes_unacknowledged    message_bytes_ram       message_bytes_persistent        head_message_timestamp  disk_reads      disk_writes     backing_queue_status    messages_paged_out      message_bytes_paged_out
<ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0.1.278.0>        test2   true    false   []              false   12      0       12      60224                           0               143384                          running [{max_heap_size,0}, {min_bin_vheap_size,46422}, {min_heap_size,233}, {fullsweep_after,65535}, {minor_gcs,2}]    12      12      0       12      2550    2550    0       2550    2550            4       8       [{mode,default}, {q1,8}, {q2,0}, {delta,{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined}}, {q3,3}, {q4,1}, {len,12}, {target_ram_count,infinity}, {next_seq_id,16392}, {avg_ingress_rate,0.018154326288234535}, {avg_egress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]    0       0
<ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0.1.1117.0>       default true    false   []              false   12      0       12      96191                           0               143384                          running [{max_heap_size,0}, {min_bin_vheap_size,46422}, {min_heap_size,233}, {fullsweep_after,65535}, {minor_gcs,2}]    12      12      0       12      2550    2550    0       2550    2550            0       12      [{mode,default}, {q1,0}, {q2,0}, {delta,{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined}}, {q3,0}, {q4,12}, {len,12}, {target_ram_count,infinity}, {next_seq_id,12}, {avg_ingress_rate,0.029199425682653112}, {avg_egress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]      0       0

Queues on /:
pid     name    durable auto_delete     arguments       owner_pid       exclusive       messages_ready  messages_unacknowledged messages        reductions      policy  exclusive_consumer_pid  exclusive_consumer_tag  consumers       consumer_utilisation    memory  slave_pids      synchronised_slave_pids recoverable_slaves      state   garbage_collection      messages_ram    messages_ready_ram      messages_unacknowledged_ram     messages_persistent     message_bytes   message_bytes_ready     message_bytes_unacknowledged    message_bytes_ram       message_bytes_persistent        head_message_timestamp  disk_reads      disk_writes     backing_queue_status    messages_paged_out      message_bytes_paged_out
<ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0.1.275.0>        test1   true    false   []              false   4       0       4       6152                            0               55712                           running [{max_heap_size,0}, {min_bin_vheap_size,46422}, {min_heap_size,233}, {fullsweep_after,65535}, {minor_gcs,9}]    4       4       0       4       850     850     0       850     850             4       0       [{mode,default}, {q1,0}, {q2,0}, {delta,{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined}}, {q3,3}, {q4,1}, {len,4}, {target_ram_count,infinity}, {next_seq_id,16384}, {avg_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_egress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]      0       0
<ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0.1.281.0>        celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   true    false   []              false   4       0       4       6222                            0               55712                           running [{max_heap_size,0}, {min_bin_vheap_size,46422}, {min_heap_size,233}, {fullsweep_after,65535}, {minor_gcs,10}]   4       4       0       4       850     850     0       850     850             4       0       [{mode,default}, {q1,0}, {q2,0}, {delta,{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined}}, {q3,3}, {q4,1}, {len,4}, {target_ram_count,infinity}, {next_seq_id,16384}, {avg_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_egress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]      0       0
<ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0.1.284.0>        test    true    false   []              false   4       0       4       6152                            0               55712                           running [{max_heap_size,0}, {min_bin_vheap_size,46422}, {min_heap_size,233}, {fullsweep_after,65535}, {minor_gcs,9}]    4       4       0       4       850     850     0       850     850             4       0       [{mode,default}, {q1,0}, {q2,0}, {delta,{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined}}, {q3,3}, {q4,1}, {len,4}, {target_ram_count,infinity}, {next_seq_id,16384}, {avg_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_egress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]      0       0
<ksaprice_rabbitmq@4eed789778c0.1.287.0>        test2   true    false   []              false   4       0       4       6162                            0               55712                           running [{max_heap_size,0}, {min_bin_vheap_size,46422}, {min_heap_size,233}, {fullsweep_after,65535}, {minor_gcs,9}]    4       4       0       4       850     850     0       850     850             4       0       [{mode,default}, {q1,0}, {q2,0}, {delta,{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined}}, {q3,3}, {q4,1}, {len,4}, {target_ram_count,infinity}, {next_seq_id,16384}, {avg_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_egress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0}, {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]      0       0

Exchanges on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:
name    type    durable auto_delete     internal        arguments       policy
        direct  true    false   false   []
amq.direct      direct  true    false   false   []
amq.fanout      fanout  true    false   false   []
amq.headers     headers true    false   false   []
amq.match       headers true    false   false   []
amq.rabbitmq.trace      topic   true    false   true    []
amq.topic       topic   true    false   false   []
celery.pidbox   fanout  false   false   false   []
celeryev        topic   true    false   false   []
default direct  true    false   false   []
reply.celery.pidbox     direct  false   false   false   []
test2   direct  true    false   false   []

Exchanges on /:
name    type    durable auto_delete     internal        arguments       policy
        direct  true    false   false   []
amq.direct      direct  true    false   false   []
amq.fanout      fanout  true    false   false   []
amq.headers     headers true    false   false   []
amq.match       headers true    false   false   []
amq.rabbitmq.log        topic   true    false   true    []
amq.rabbitmq.trace      topic   true    false   true    []
amq.topic       topic   true    false   false   []
celeryev        topic   true    false   false   []
celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   direct  true    false   false   []
test    direct  true    false   false   []
test1   direct  true    false   false   []
test2   direct  true    false   false   []

Bindings on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:
source_name     source_kind     destination_name        destination_kind        routing_key     arguments       vhost
        exchange        default queue   default []      ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh
        exchange        test2   queue   test2   []      ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh
default exchange        default queue   default []      ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh
test2   exchange        test2   queue   test2   []      ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh

Bindings on /:
source_name     source_kind     destination_name        destination_kind        routing_key     arguments       vhost
        exchange        celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   queue   celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   []      /
        exchange        test    queue   test    []      /
        exchange        test1   queue   test1   []      /
        exchange        test2   queue   test2   []      /
celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   exchange        celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   queue   celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb   []      /
test    exchange        test    queue   test    []      /
test1   exchange        test1   queue   test1   []      /
test2   exchange        test2   queue   test2   []      /

Consumers on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:

Consumers on /:

Permissions on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:
user    configure       write   read
admin   .*      .*      .*

Permissions on /:
user    configure       write   read
guest   .*      .*      .*

Policies on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:

Policies on /:

Parameters on ksaprice_rabbitmq_vh:

Parameters on /:
```

**update**:
The module version I tried: airflow 1.8 with celery 3.x, airflow 1.8.1 with celery 4.1 and with celery 3.1.25, none of the combinations resolved this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking into why I had a similar issue, the worker kept listening to a queue prefixed with celeryev.{hashvalue} and not to default, even when I set -q=default.  The answer to my problem was setting the environment variable C_FORCE_ROOT=true in the workers environment as the worker was running as root (I understand this is not recommended and a huge security risk if one is not careful about network access)

C_FORCE_ROOT=true

I set this, restarted the worker and it ran fine.

You can see in the code that the worker is disallowed when this is not the case:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/platforms.html